# Can you use a 'to' infinitive instead of using 'by ~ing'?

Tags: infinitives

> *To identify human genes and understand their roles* allows researchers to discover the cause of various diseases.

To contain the meaning of 'by ~ing' or 'while ~ing', can you use 'to infinite' like in the example above?

Comment: This is all wrong. You should try the English Learners forum.

Comment: well that sentence was from english translation book. but thanks for the comment.

Comment: Don't use _by_. Just the gerund clause, with two gerunds. _Identifying human genes and understanding their roles allows researchers to discover the cause of various diseases._ A gerund is preferred to an infinitive for subject clauses.